# Visualizing Imaginary Roots of $f(x) = \cos(x) + \cosh^2(x) = 0$

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics

I was wondering if there is a way to show the four imaginary roots of the function

$$f(x) = \cos(x) + \cosh^2(x) = 0$$

We can find the four imaginary roots using

```
f[x_] := Cos[x] + Cosh[x]^2

Reduce[f[z] == 0 && Abs[z] < 2, z]
```

I have tried several things, but no luck so far, for example

```
ContourPlot[{y == Cosh[x], y == Sqrt[-Cos[x]], y == -Sqrt[-Cos[x]]}, {x, -6., 6.}, {y, -6.,6.}]
```

Is there any way to show these complex roots visually?

Comment: Maybe `ComplexPlot[f[z], {z, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}, 
 ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbs"]`

Comment: or `ColorFunction -> "CyclicArg"`

Comment: That provides more information than the existence of a zero it tells you the multiplicity of the zero according to cyclic frequency of the colors as explained in the details section of `ComplexPlot`

Comment: @userrandrand: That second plot is beautiful! I cannot believe I missed this command and the one in the answer! Thanks!

Comment: I also like how pretty they  look (:. Thanks for giving me an excuse to look at one haha

Comment: I checked your profile description found it amusing then left to do something else and later recalled something funny an internship advisor told me back in 2016. First, I should mention that the metric in general relativity is often denoted $g_{\mu,\nu}$ and pronounced "g mu nu".  To emphasize the importance of writing results he told me something  like,  we do not know if cows are working on differential geometry when alone on the grass because they do not write. After all,  who knows if that mooo is referencing the first index of the metric ( mu ).

Comment: Aren’t there infinite roots as seen in [this complex plot](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#cos(z)%2Bcosh(z)%5E2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Cos[x] + Cosh[x]^2
```

The exact solutions are [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
sol = {Reduce[f[z] == 0 && Abs[z] < 2, z] // ToRules}
```

[image]

Their approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {{z -> -1.02195 - 1.19864 I}, {z -> -1.02195 + 1.19864 I}, {z -> 
   1.02195 - 1.19864 I}, {z -> 1.02195 + 1.19864 I}} *)
```

Plotting,

```
ListPlot[ReIm[z] /. sol,
 AxesLabel -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Use [`ComplexContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexContourPlot.html)

```
ComplexContourPlot[
 ReIm[Cos[z] + Cosh[z]^2],
 {z, -1.5 - 1.5 I, 1.5 + 1.5 I},
 Contours -> {{0}, {0}},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[ReIm /@ (z /. sol)]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon, not exactly what I had in mind. I was hoping that we could have a graphical representation showing the functions and their intersections (like you see with real functions). Maybe that is just not possible, and this is the best that can be done.  I was hoping I would have seen those intersections in the contour plot I drew, but no such luck. + 1

Comment: @Moo:  It's possible.  Consider the complex function $f(z)=\cos(z)+\cosh^2(z)$.  Now plot separately, the real and imaginary surfaces of these two functions.   That is, let $z=r e^{it}$.   Next plot where they are both zero or intersecting the complex z-plane.  This results in contour lines.  Where the contour lines intersect are the zeros.  Nice if you can plot the contour lines over each real and imaginary surface!

Comment: @BobHanlon: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @josh you can also plot directly the phase using `ComplexPlot[f[z], {z, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I},   ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbs"]`. At a zero or a pole f[z] behaves like $z^m$ (after shifting to the position of the pole or zero) and so $r^m e^{m i t}$ and thus as an oscillator with frequency m.  That has the advantage that it also shows the multiplicity of the zero or pole (and it is nice eye candy to look at).

Comment: @josh Technically it should be `ColorFunction -> "CyclicArg"` according to what I said but I prefer the look of `"CyclicLogAbs"`